# Adjoint operator $0^\times$ of $0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am currently self-studying the section of the Adjoint Operators of Normed Spaces (which are not necessarily Hilbert spaces) from Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications.

The current example I am trying to do is

> What are the adjoints of a zero operator $0$ and an identity operator $I$?

I got the adjoint of $I$ as follows:

\begin{align}(I^\times g)(x) &= g(Ix) \\
\therefore I^\times (g(x))&= g(x),\end{align} i.e. $I^\times = I$.

I am now trying to find $0^\times$ as follows:
\begin{align}(0^\times g)(x) &= g(0x) \\
\therefore 0^\times(g(x))&= g(0). \end{align}
How do I continue with this to find an explicit form for $0^\times$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $g$ is a linear functional and thus $g(0) = 0$ so

$$ (0^x g)(x) = g(0(x)) = g(0) = 0 $$

for all $g$ and $x$ which implies that $0^x = 0$ (where the right hand side is the zero operator on the dual space).

Comment: Oh yes of course!! $g(0)= g(0x)= 0g(x) =0$ (where $0$ here represents the scalar $0$). How did I miss that?? lol!